# How are pymc3 variables assigned to the currently active model?

Tags: python, pymc3

In [PyMC3](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started) you can do this

```
basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=Y)
```

and all the variables (`pm.Normal`, ...) will be "assigned" to the `basic_model` instance.

[From the docs](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started)

> The first line,
>
> ```
> basic_model = Model()
> ```
>
> creates a new Model object which is a container for the model random
>   variables.
>
> Following instantiation of the model, the subsequent specification of
>   the model components is performed inside a with statement:
>
> ```
> with basic_model:
> ```
>
> This creates a context manager, with our basic_model as the context,
>   that includes all statements until the indented block ends. This means
>   all PyMC3 objects introduced in the indented code block below the with
>   statement are added to the model behind the scenes. Absent this
>   context manager idiom, we would be forced to manually associate each
>   of the variables with basic_model right after we create them. If you
>   try to create a new random variable without a with model: statement,
>   it will raise an error since there is no obvious model for the
>   variable to be added to.

I think it is very elegant for the purpose of the library. How is that actually implemented?

The only way I can think of is something in the spirit of this:

```
class Model:
    active_model = None
    def __enter__(self):
        Model.active_model = self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Model.active_model = None

class Normal:
    def __init__(self):
        if Model.active_model is None:
            raise ValueError("cant instantiate variable outside of Model")
        else:
            self.model = Model.active_model
```

It works with my simple REPL tests but I am not sure if this have some pitfalls and is actually that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close, and it was even quite similar to your implementation for a while.  Note that `threading.local` is used to store objects, and it is maintained as a list to allow nesting multiple models, and allows multiprocessing. There is a little extra in the actual implementation to allow setting `theano` configuration when entering a model context that I deleted:

```
class Context(object):
    contexts = threading.local()

    def __enter__(self):
        type(self).get_contexts().append(self)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        type(self).get_contexts().pop()

    @classmethod
    def get_contexts(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls.contexts, 'stack'):
            cls.contexts.stack = []
        return cls.contexts.stack

    @classmethod
    def get_context(cls):
        """Return the deepest context on the stack."""
        try:
            return cls.get_contexts()[-1]
        except IndexError:
            raise TypeError("No context on context stack")
```

The `Model` class subclasses `Context`, so when writing algorithms we can call `Model.get_context()` from inside a context manager and have access to the object. This is equivalent to your `Model.active_model`.